# How to subscribe message coming from a package of ROS into Python code of another package?

Tags: ros, python

I am using `darknet_ros_3d` package and getting the published 3D coordinates. Now I need to subscribe these coordinates into a Python file (`main.py`) of another package named `kth-ros-pkg/yumi_demos`. The code of `main.py` is given as below:

```
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import yumi_moveit_utils as yumi
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from std_srvs.srv import Empty




def close_grippers(arm):
    """Closes the grippers.
    Closes the grippers with an effort of 15 and then relaxes the effort to 0.
    :param arm: The side to be closed (moveit_utils LEFT or RIGHT)
    :type arm: int
    :returns: Nothing
    :rtype: None
    """
    yumi.gripper_effort(arm, 15.0)
    yumi.gripper_effort(arm, 0.0)

def open_grippers(arm):
    """Opens the grippers.
    Opens the grippers with an effort of -15 and then relaxes the effort to 0.
    :param arm: The side to be opened (moveit_utils LEFT or RIGHT)
    :type arm: int
    :returns: Nothing
    :rtype: None
    """
    yumi.gripper_effort(arm, -15.0)
    yumi.gripper_effort(arm, 0.0)



def move_and_grasp(arm, pose_ee, grip_effort):
    try:
        yumi.traverse_path([pose_ee], arm, 10)
    except Exception:
        if (arm == yumi.LEFT):
            yumi.plan_and_move(yumi.group_l, yumi.create_pose_euler(pose_ee[0], pose_ee[1], pose_ee[2], pose_ee[3], pose_ee[4], pose_ee[5]))
        elif (arm == yumi.RIGHT):
            yumi.plan_and_move(yumi.group_r, yumi.create_pose_euler(pose_ee[0], pose_ee[1], pose_ee[2], pose_ee[3], pose_ee[4], pose_ee[5]))

    if (grip_effort <= 20 and grip_effort >= -20):
        yumi.gripper_effort(arm, grip_effort)
    else:
        print("The gripper effort values should be in the range [-20, 20]")




def run():
    """Starts the node
    Runs to start the node and initialize everthing. Runs forever via Spin()
    :returns: Nothing
    :rtype: None
    """

    rospy.init_node('yumi_moveit_demo')

    #Start by connecting to ROS and MoveIt!
    yumi.init_Moveit()


    # Print current joint angles
    yumi.print_current_joint_states(yumi.RIGHT)
    yumi.print_current_joint_states(yumi.LEFT)

    # Reset YuMi joints to "home" position
    yumi.reset_pose()


    # Drive YuMi end effectors to a desired position (pose_ee), and perform a grasping task with a given effort (grip_effort)
    # Gripper effort: opening if negative, closing if positive, static if zero
    pose_ee = [0.3, 0.15, 0.2, 0.0, 3.14, 3.14]
    grip_effort = -10.0
    move_and_grasp(yumi.LEFT, pose_ee, grip_effort)

    pose_ee = [0.3, -0.15, 0.2, 0.0, 3.14, 3.14]
    grip_effort = -10.0
    move_and_grasp(yumi.RIGHT, pose_ee, grip_effort)

    rospy.spin()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run()

        print "####################################     Program finished     ####################################"
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

And I am getting coordinates from the `darknet` package in the following format:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1593723845
    nanosec: 430724839
  frame_id: camera_link
bounding_boxes:
- object_name: person
  probability: 0.7609682679176331
  xmin: 0.4506256580352783
  ymin: -0.3164764642715454
  xmax: 0.7936256527900696
  ymax: 0.11368180811405182
  zmin: -0.25958430767059326
  zmax: 0.10506562888622284
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to messages from a different package is no different than from the same package, just make sure to get the topic name right in case of [namespaces](https://answers.ros.org/question/314560/namespaces-of-nodes/).

The `rospy` [Subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber#The_Code_Explained-1) shows how to create a subscriber for a topic:

```
rospy.Subscriber(<topic_name>, <msg_type>, <callback_function>)
```

A [quick search](https://github.com/IntelligentRoboticsLabs/gb_visual_detection_3d/blob/master/darknet_ros_3d/config/darknet_3d.yaml) shows the topic of interest for you might be `/darknet_ros_3d/bounding_boxes`? If that's so, import the corresponding message type from [gb_visual_detection_3d_msgs](https://github.com/IntelligentRoboticsLabs/gb_visual_detection_3d_msgs):

```
from gb_visual_detection_3d_msgs.msg import BoundingBoxes3d
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @MorganStark47. Here, pose_ee takes the constant values (as shown above in main.py file). Can you please guide me that how can I add the subscriber code to the main.py file and then how to store the continuously coming messages (in the form of x, y, z coordinates) in pose_ee?